# HoverIntent causing elements to break on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, break, pyrocms, hoverintent

The project I'm currently working on shows a number of people's pictures who are attending an event and I would like a hover event to occur that displays their name. I've gotten this to work but it also causes the images to become misaligned in doing so. Here is the code...

```
JS

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".foo").hoverIntent(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.eventattendee').fadeIn();
  }, function() {
    $('.eventattendee').fadeOut();
  });
});



HTML

{{ event:get_attendees_of_event event_id="<?php echo $event['event_id']; ?>" }}
  {{ user:profile user_id="{{ attendee_id }}" }}
    <div class="wrapper">
      <a class="foo" href="/user_account/id/{{ attendee_id }}" >
        <img src="{{ profile_picture:image }}" class="bigimgsize organizersize has-tip tip-top" data-width="auto" title="{{ first_name }} {{ last_name }}"/>
      </a>
      <div class="eventattendee">
        <h1>{{ first_name }} {{ last_name }}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  {{ /user:profile }}
{{ /event:get_attendees_of_event }}


CSS

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.eventattendee {
  display:none; 
  position: relative; 
  top: 19%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Are we supposed to know magically know how you have the CSS set up for it to be displayed? You will need to remove elements from the flow. Guessing some absolute positioning will help there.

Comment: your eventattendee div is breaking the layout, try setting it to position absolute so it doesn't mess up the DOM flow.

Comment: epasarello: Added the relevant CSS files. My bad

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the simple answer in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberjetx/U5NBX/):

js

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".foo img").hover(function () {
        $(this).next("em").animate({
            opacity: "show",
            top: "0"
        }, "slow");
    }, function () {
        $(this).next("em").animate({
            opacity: "hide",
            top: "300"
        }, "slow");
    });
});
```

html: Note the addition of the em tag. You can of course rip the title attrib and add an em then append the text... but why go through all of that.

```
<div class="wrapper"> <a class="foo" href="#">
    <img src="blah" class="bigimgsize organizersize has-tip tip-top" data-width="auto" />
<em>first last addl info</em> 
  </a>
```

css:

```
.foo {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10 2px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.foo em {
  width: 190px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 3px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: I went a little crazy and used some quicksand and allowed the filtering of events based on tags and some crazy animation. AND your sliding details.   

This solution uses an unordered list rather than divs...  

http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberjetx/pP37F/

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue with onmouseover before, and it happens when an absolute position hasn't been set. The newly shown content takes area on the browser grid, and subsequent content moves further down the grid to allow for the new space.

This simple code can fix the issue:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:249px; left:435px; width:233px; height:700px;">
</div>
```